# User input manipulation in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, string-concatenation

Hi I am creating a batch file to execute my test cases.
And want to take input from user which test case he/she want to run like

Enter ID{1,2,3,4,5}:
And i have to manipulate user input in my batch file 
Suppose if user provide 1,2
then i have to split the string using delims "," and start a loop which will add all input in a command like -
execute_test 1 2

I am totally new to batch files so anyone can help me with a simple solution ?

Answer (score 0):

save the file like:

user input is listed and can be accessed using %number, for example:

shutdown.bat:

```
shutdown /m \\%1
```

command line:

```
shutdown.bat computer1
```

will cause the command:

```
shutdown /m \\computer1
```

to run

Answer (score 0):

use the `set` command to get user input.

Use `for` command to process it's Elements (working if delimited with default delimiters like spaces, commas or semicolons).

```
set /p "input=Please enter testcases: "
echo %input%
for %%i in (%Input%) do (
  echo working on %%i
  rem do other usefull stuff
)
echo finished.
```

test run:

```
C:\test>test.bat
Please enter testcases: 1,5,8
1,5,8
working on 1
working on 5
working on 8
finished.

C:\test>
```

see `set /?`, `for /?`

Comment: Thanks Stephan It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Choice is another option..

CHOICE can be used to set a specific %errorlevel%
for example to set the %errorlevel% to 6 :

```
ECHO 6| CHOICE /C 123456 /N >NUL
```

http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: `choice` is a very good option to get a single char, but OP requires a string containing some options

Comment: by the way: Setting the errorlevel is much easier: `cmd /c "exit 543"`